# $\text{limsup}|a_n|^{1/n}\geq \text{limsup}|a_{2n}|^{1/n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

The question is very simple. Is it true that $\text{limsup}|a_n|^{1/n}\geq \text{limsup}|a_{2n}|^{1/n} $ where $<a_n>$ is some real sequence? Can this be proved or disproved? And also what if I make the following change to the inequality; $\text{limsup}|a_n|^{1/n}\geq \text{limsup}|a_{2n}|^{1/2n} $. Does it make a difference to the answer? Hope someone can help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\limsup|a_n | ^{1/n} ≥\limsup|a_{ 2n} | ^{1/2n} $$

is true. The other one is not.

This is because any subsequence of $( u_{2n})$ is also a subsequence of
$(u_n)$.

Comment: Thanks but I still cannot see how the other inequality is not true.

Comment: @Heisenberg consider $u_n = 2^n$ for instance. you get $2\ge\infty$.